# Why use "Void" with arguments in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, functional-programming

I am new to C# programming and cannot understand the reasoning for using arguments? Doesn't the keyword "void" means nothing is being returned? Such as:

```
void Start() {
  AddTwoNumbers(number1, number2);
}

void DisplayResult(int total) {
  Debug.Log("The total is: " + total);
}
```

Comment: No arguments is not the same as no return value. Input and Output.

Comment: Why shouldnt that be acceptable, the argument can easily be there to control the flow inside the "void" method, and many other reasons.

Comment: Nothing being returned doesn't mean *does nothing*. The code you *posted* does nothing, because `start` calls `AddTwoNumbers`, and you don't have a function named `AddTwoNumbers`.

Comment: they are completely unrelated things

Comment: @Servy question is explicitly marked as "functional-programming" (I suspect due to lack of "method-programming" :) rather than actual understanding of what "functional programming" stands for). Was not exactly the most serious comment (but good search idea - "what would be usage of functions that done return anything in pure functional programming")

Comment: I would suggest output (e.g. `Console.WriteLine`). See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15269/why-are-side-effects-considered-evil-in-functional-programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Think of a function call (or procedure call) as a conversation.

If I issue you a request to go away and expect no reply, the return value would be void. Even though the argument for `go` equals `away`.

However, a function call could be used to obtain a result. Imagine going to the store (`go` equals `store`) and expecting the function to return what was brought from the store. In this case, the return type could then be `chocolate` or `bread`.

Answer (score 1):

From a basic understanding, `void` is a return type, or rather a lack of return type, meaning that the function will not return a value. I.e. you can call the function as a procedure that changes some state.

Any arguments are provided when calling the function to facilitate its task or calculation.

In the above example, you mentioned number1, number2 arguments that facilitate "addition" operations.